# file_field Browse button customize

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can i customize the file field "Browse" button in ruby on rails. cutomise in sense i want to change the button color and style. Is this possible in ROR? If so , can any one help me out ....

Comment: That's not specific to Rails, it's part of the browser. I don't know how to customize it, but try tagging your question with CSS - you may get more responses.

Answer (score 2):

All Rails' `file_field` helper does is make it easier to create a file input, rather than having to code HTML directly (ie. `<input type="file" ...>`). Unfortunately, the file input is not very styleable, and the button especially tends to be stuck to the way the browser defines it should look.

However, there are some techniques/hacks for tricking the browser into making the browse button look how you want it, by making use of CSS and Javascript. You can take a look at an article about it on [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html). However, as this makes use of the CSS `opacity` property, the input will not look right in browsers that do not support it. As well, there are some other problems with this approach, as outlined in the article.