# Custom caption text for file_field helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view-helpers

Is it possible to provide your own caption for the button that the file_field helper generates?

Comment: @Layke - It shows you don't know rails, your answer is completely wrong. Please refrain from answering questions you have no idea about.

Comment: @Mukul Goel - Please don't just jump on the band wagon, evaluate the merit of others comments yourself rather than taking them as gospel. The previous commenter did not have the answer.

Comment: I believe this is a html question, and not a rails helper question. As mentioned in the answer below, it's not really possible without some hacks. As to the reply by @Layke, he has no idea what he is talking about, I'll highlight is answer to an admin.

Comment: Removed ambiguous/wrong comment.

Comment: @MukulGoel - an apology would go a long way, or please justify why your comment is still relevant.

Comment: @herbil : My comment is not relevant anymore and I am removing it. Thank you for bringing it up and I apologize for jumping to conclusion. :-) #Peace. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check this answer for your case:
[How to change the button text of <input type="file" />?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944267/how-to-change-the-button-text-of-input-type-file)

The answer will show you how to do it which you can implement in rails views.

Comment: thanks, it hadn't crossed my mind that this wan't a rails problem

Answer (score 1):

Also some tips here: 
[file_field Browse button customize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099702/file-field-browse-button-customize),
[quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html)

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, the rails helper doesn't really allow you to change the text by default. You may tweak it using CSS.

**html.erb file**

```
  <%= file_field_tag "file", class: "inputfile" %>
  <%= label_tag :file, "Any text here", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

**css file**

```
.inputfile {
    width: 0.1px;
    height: 0.1px;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

**Here's a preview:**

[image]

If you want more customisation [this](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/09/15/styling-customizing-file-inputs-smart-way/) is a great guide!