# Is there a way to customize form_for buttons?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm currently using rails form_for to build a form, but I would like know if there is a way to use an custom icon as buttons for the form instead of the button like the below image.

[image]
...

This is what I did but it doesn't work.

### _form.html.erb

```
 <%= f.file_field :avatar, class: "test" %>  #
```

### .css

```
     .test {
    background: url('/images/icon.png') no-repeat left top;
}
```

Comment: Update button you can change by this css-   input[type="submit"]{
  background: url("icon.png");
} and for browse i am not sure because this whole is a one button including no file selected

Comment: See This:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099702/file-field-browse-button-customize

Comment: no its not that complicated as mention in above comments, its pretty simple
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-file_field
please share corresponding HTML and please double check your css file/image path

Comment: Google search 'pretty file upload buttons'

Comment: You cannot do it in Rails because each browser implements `<input type="file"...>` itself, including how the "browse" button looks.  You have to do it in CSS instead - I used this article to make a solution: https://coderwall.com/p/4etjja

Answer (score 0):

I think the format of how you defined your class in ruby is incorrect. Try this link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5316059/3507417

or:

```
<%= f.file_field :avatar, :class => 'submit_class_name_here' %>
```